# nav не вмещается в 1 строку

Tags: html, css

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

}

body {
    max-width: 1440px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
    max-width: 1256px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

$color1: #E3B873;
$color2: #fff;
$font1: FuturaDemiC,
sans serif;
$font2: FuturaBookC;
$font3: Yeseva One;
$bgcolor: #131313;


.main-header {
    background-color: $bgcolor;
    padding-top: 24px;
    padding-bottom: 23px;
}

.main-navigation {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;

    h1 {
        color: $color1;
        font-family: $font1;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 16px;
        margin-right: 95px;
    }

    a {
        color: $color1;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 16px;
    }

    .main-navigation__contacts {
        margin-left: 67px;
    }

    button {
        font-family: $font1;
        color: $color2;
        font-size: 13px;
        line-height: 15px;
        padding: 10px 26px;
        background-color: $color1;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 2px;
        margin-left: 45px;
    }
}

.site-navigation {
    display: flex;
    color: $color2;
    font-family: $font2;

    li {
        font-size: 14px;
        list-style: none;
        margin-right: 47px;
        cursor: pointer;
        line-height: 16px;

        &:last-child {
            margin-right: 0;
        }
    }

    &:first-child {
        color: $color1;
    }
}
```

Задаю все размеры padding, margin, line-height, font-size строго по тому как показывает figma, но  nav все равно не вмещается в заданные размеры
 [image: figma[![то как в браузере]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxbx4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

уменьши padding в кнопках/ссылках,
Figma - пока что очень сырая программа, опять же у тебя может быть макет под совершенно другие размеры экрана.